# Construction of matrix failed

Tags: r

Why is my below statement in R failing? I am trying to fill the matrix by column instead of rows.

```
>matrix.new <-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),nrow=2,bycol=true)
Error in matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), nrow = 2, bycol = true) : 
  unused argument(s) (bycol = true)
```

I want the matrix to be like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Suggestions?

Comment: suppress `bycol=true`

Comment: i want it to fill first 3 columns and then move to next row. ncol=3,doesn't work

Comment: The default is already by column because `byrow` is set to `FALSE`. I don't think the `bycol` argument exists, and, finally, `TRUE,FALSE` must be typed with all capital letters.

Comment: `bycol` does not exsist for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to fill the matrix row-wise, hence you want

```
matrix.new <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
```

Comment: The question seems to be opposite: he wants to fill by column, that's why I cannot see what is his problem, he just has to specify the first two arguments, dropping the `byrow` argument.

Comment: @DavidePassaretti, if he will just drop the `bycol` argument he won't get the desired output

Comment: @DavidArenburg you are right, because he edited his question filling by row and I didn't notice that... At the beginning, when I read the question, he had filled by column.

Comment: @DavidePassaretti The question is ambigious. The texts is in contrast to the desired output example.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get is quite informative. `matrix` does not take the argument `bycol`. Consult the documentation `?matrix` and see that it takes `byrow`. Furthermore you should use `TRUE` and not `true`.

So something like

```
matrix.new <-matrix(1:6, 2, 3, byrow = TRUE)
print(matrix.new)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    4    5    6
```

will give you what you want.

Comment: I am new to R and I was studying from tutorials, it stated that we can use bycol. and i realised by default its by col,until we want to fill by row for byrow.